# Factoring Polynomials

Tags: function-construction, polynomials

I have defined the following function

```
g[v_] := (
   l = FactorList[v];
   Return[Product[Sum[l[[x]][[1]]^y, {y, 0,l[[x]][[2]]}], {x, 1, Length[l]}]])`
```

I expected `g[x+1]` to return `2(x+2)`, but it returns `8` instead. Similarly `g[x+2]` returns `10` instead of `2(x+3)`. What is wrong with the function definition?

Comment: What have you done thus far to debug it?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Not much, I really don't see where this goes wrong :(

Comment: If you add `Print[l];` right after that `Product[` (so right before `Sum[...]`) it might become clear. This is the sort of thing one does to debug unexpected behavior.

Comment: using `l` for variable name is really not a good idea at all. It looks like `1`.

Comment: Another debugging tip. When you get a numeric result from a function when you expect a symbolic one, try changing symbolic arguments given to the function to use variables that do not appear in its code body. For instance, if you had tried giving `g` the argument `u +1`, `g` would have evaluated to `2(2 + u)` causing, I hope, an alarm to sound in your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use a global variable as your index in the `Product`, and it is the same global variable `x` you give as an input, e.g. compute `g[z+1]` and you will get what you expect. 
To solve this issue you should localize your iterator `x`. For example like this, using `Module`:

```
g[v_] := Module[{x, y, l},
  l = FactorList[v];
  Product[Sum[l[[x, 1]]^y, {y, 0, l[[x, 2]]}], {x, 1, Length[l]}]
]
```

Here I also localized `y` and `l`, and removed the `Return`, as it is unnecessary.